# Disable notification center on lock screen (or prevent it from clearing notifications)

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

One of the must utterly *infuriating* problems I have on recent iOS versions is the fact that swiping down from the top of the screen while the phone is locked will bring down the notification center and *clear* all of my lock screen notifications.

This happens all. the. time. I usually keep my phone in my pocket, and if I get a message or feel it vibrate, I will reach into my pocket and with my thumb and forefinger pull it out. Perhaps 50% of the time when I do this, my thumb ends up pulling the notification center down when I pull my phone out.

This alone isn't a big deal, I can just swipe it up again. The *problem* is that when the notification center comes down, for some god-knows-why reason, it clears the notifications that were just on the screen, meaning I'm now prevented from doing precisely what I pulled the phone out of my pocket for in the first place.

There has got to be a way to fix this horrible UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, I ended up solving this shortly after I posted the question. [This article](http://www.imore.com/how-disable-notification-center-lock-screen-your-iphone-and-ipad) ended up solving it for me.

In summary:

1. Open Settings
2. Go to Touch ID & Passcode
3. (Enter passcode)
4. Scroll down to "Allow Access When Locked"
5. Disable *both* "Today" and "Notifications View"

Now there is no swiping down from the top at all on the lock screen (but still available if unlocked). Thank goodness!